# The best approach for storing Facebook/Google Sign up user data

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-login, google-signin

I have a website where the user can sign in via email and password. Additionally I want to give to user the possibility to sign up/ login via Facebook and Google. 
Now after successful signup via Google/Facebook when I get from Google/Facebook a response with user data, should I store those data to a separate tables? Then I would have 3 tables with user accounts - 1 for Facebook users, 1 for Google users, and one for default email/password users. Or is it a better approach to keep everything in one table?

Answer (score 0):

Open-ended question with opinionated responses....

You should (imo) base an account on the default email, both facebook and google return the email associated with the account and assign a surrogate for each user to associate other data with that account. 
How you store the other data (tokens, fb/google ids) is up to you. Keep one account table, and one account per email.